# Address history in Background Check

Tags: background-check

If a background check runs an address history for one individual, but another individual living at the same address has criminal background, can that be held against the original person? I.E. cause them to fail the background check?

Answer (score 1):

The address is just another way to identify you. They may find incident information that gives date, name, age, address and reason for ticket or arrest. If the name is yours and the age is correct and the address fits the time frame you lived there, the background check may flag it. They may want more to know more details.

For a multiple year window that you lived in a large jurisdiction more than one SJM could have been arrested or given a traffic ticket. So they need to differentiate the bad SJMs from the you the good SJM.

Comment: SJM?  What does this mean?

Comment: SJM is the username of the OP who asked the question.